# My application has the camera access permission by default.How can i turned it off and ask for permission?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, camera, user-permissions

I am using camera in my application, and i want to ask for that trendy permission which every other app prompts. How can i get that ?

```
AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // do your logic
    authorized = YES;
     [self actionLaunchAppCamera];

} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){
    // denied
    authorized = NO;

} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
    // restricted, normally won't happen
} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
    // not determined?!
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if(granted){
            NSLog(@"Granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);



        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);
        }
    }];
} else {
    // impossible, unknown authorization status
}
```

I am using the above code for checking authorization but it always go inside authorizedstatus condition as it has the permission already. I have checked from privacy settings the permission is already on. But i have never ask for the permission from user.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: try to run application in different simultor and check its ask the permission or not

Comment: i am directly running it on device.

Comment: just for cross checked run application on simulator and check.

Comment: because in your real device if you give permission once and delete the app and again run it will automatically give permission as device data is still in cache  memory

Comment: Yeah i am thinking the same, it is not a problem but it is a behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Oh, I see what you mean.  Then you need to create AVCaptureDeviceInput to see whether permission has been asked before.  If not, this prompts the user for permission.

```
NSError outError = NULL;
AVCaptureDevice captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
If (captureDevice != NULL) {
AVCaptureDeviceInput captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputfromDevice:captureDevice error:outError];
    If (captureInput != NULL && outError == NULL) {
        // we have permission to use the camera
    }
}
```

You don't have to uninstall the app to reset the access permission.  Assuming your device is running iOS 8, simply go to the camera settings screen and disable the access:

1. Exit the app
2. Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Camera
3. Look for your app to turn the switch off
4. Run the app

Comment: it never pop up the authorization check again because it is the first time check, it will just not open the camera up and the if else conditions which i have shared with you on denied you have to pop a message by yourself.

Comment: To reset the access permission you should go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: @akc is it possible to change the permission dilog box (camera persmission) text to chineese ? how to do it have any idea?